# Ansible adds the crontask on each apply

Tags: cron, ansible

I have added the following line to cron to run the script on reboot

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/autostart.sh
```

But when I prepared the ansible script for it I found that it adds 1 more line each time I apply the ansible.

The task is below:

```
- name: Add autostart script to cron
  cron:
    special_time: reboot
    user: user
    state: present
    job: /usr/local/bin/autostart.sh
```

And after several updates I get the following cron:

```
#Ansible: None
@reboot /usr/local/bin/autostart.sh
#Ansible: None
@reboot /usr/local/bin/autostart.sh
#Ansible: None
@reboot /usr/local/bin/autostart.sh
#Ansible: None
@reboot /usr/local/bin/autostart.sh
```

As for me this is strange behavior because `state: present` should check if the record is already present.

Or maybe have I missed anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add *name* parameter. For example

```
- name: Add autostart script to cron
  cron:
    name: "autostart"
    special_time: reboot
    user: user
    state: present
    job: /usr/local/bin/autostart.sh
```

Quoting from [cron](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cron_module.html#cron-manage-cron-d-and-crontab-entries)

> name: Description of a crontab entry or, if env is set, the name of environment variable. Required if state=absent. Note that **if name is not set and state=present, then a new crontab entry will always be created, regardless of existing ones**. This parameter will always be required in future releases.

Comment: yes, that's it, thank you! I've read the man again and already found it.